# templated circular inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, circular-dependency, incomplete-type

in this code, compiler complain about **undefined** `MyClassB`, which is understandable :

```
class MyClassA;
class MyClassB;

template <class T> class BaseClass : public T {
};

class MyClassA : public BaseClass<MyClassB> {
};

class MyClassB : public BaseClass<MyClassA> {
};
```

but in this code, compile is **successful and no complain** about `MyClassB` :

```
class MyClassA;
class MyClassB;

template <class T> class BaseClass : public T {
};

class MyClassA : public BaseClass<std::vector<MyClassB>> {
};

class MyClassB : public BaseClass<std::vector<MyClassA>> {
};
```

why the second code compile, since `MyClassB` is not yet defined when constructing `std::vector<MyClassB>`?

Comment: Tangentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074872/typedef-and-incomplete-type

Comment: good quality standard library implementations have flags that enable the check of such conditions. For example, libstdc++: http://codepad.org/aq9eOhHO

Comment: (there is no CRTP going on here. The code says `class MyClassB : BaseClass<... MyClassA ...>`, rather than `class MyClassB : BaseClass<... MyClassB ...>`. Therefor, I removed that tag to include "circular-dependency" and "incomplete-type" which appear to be the two main problems here). It's late, so I might have missed some better combination of tags. Sadly, saying "class-template" will not have the tag "template", which this question really should be tagged as. Splitting it into two tags would require 6 tags...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your implementation of `std::vector` allows an incomplete type. This is a side effect of the instantiation rules of member functions of class templates: they aren't instantiated until they're used. So the functions that *do* need it to be a complete type aren't instantiated, yet. So no errors.

Contrarily, it does need to be a complete type to be a base class, so you get an error in that case.

---

However, it's actually undefined behavior to pass an incomplete type to `std::vector` (or any other standard library container), and "it works" is a valid undefined outcome. You shouldn't do it.

Comment: if i do `class A : public std::vector<B>` and `class B : public std::vector<A>` is this lead to undefined behaviour too?

Comment: @uray: Yes, because of `std::vector<B>`; `B` is incomplete.

Comment: @Gman : that's weird, that codes compile and work as expected on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @uray: Yes, "works as expected" is an unfortunate possible outcome of undefined behavior. :) That code is free to do anything on any C++ compiler.

Comment: @GMan: any suggestion to solve circular inheritance dependency like that?

Comment: @uray: Depends on what you're trying to do. The solution to such an abstract problem is: don't. What's your real situation? Note the innate impossibility of your former code block: `MyClassA` has (through `BaseClass`) `MyClassB` as a base, which has (again, through `BaseClass`) `MyClassA` as a base. `A` is a base of `B` is a base of `A` is a base of `B`, etc...it's logically incoherent.

Comment: I'am trying to create a "tree": instance of class A has child of class B and instance of type B has child of type A. which I solve by creating Tree of type A as `class A : public std::vector<B>` and for tree of B :`class B: public std::vector<A>`

Comment: @uray: Better consider using composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: @Xeo: That doesn't solve the issue at hand, that's still infinite regression.

Comment: @GMan: Yes, but you could at least control when to stop if you use pointer... and you can use forward declarations then. :) But aside from that, the basic idea of this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the "[Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)".

Your `BaseClass` class uses its template argument as a base class, which requires a complete type.

The second version of the code just passes the template argument to another template, an incomplete type is allowed in that case, if the second template doesn't do anything requiring a complete type.  If you used the argument in any way that required a complete type, it wouldn't be allowed either.