# How to declare two classes such that A has members of B and B marks members of A as friends?

Tags: c++, class, friend, forward-declaration

I am attempting to do exercise 7.32 from C++ Primer 5th Edition. That exercise asks the following:

> Define your own versions of `Screen` and `Window_mgr` in which `clear` is a member of `Window_mgr` and a friend of `Screen`.

Here are the definitions for `Screen`, `Window_mgr` and `clear` given in the text.

```
class Screen
{
  public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) { }
  private:
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;
};

class Window_mgr
{
  public:
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear(ScreenIndex);
  private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{Screen(24, 80 ' ')};
};

void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
  Screen &s = screens[i];
  s.contents = std::string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}
```

Now those two classes, if defined Screen first than Window_mgr work as I expect. Now, the exercise asks me to make `clear` a friend of Screen and define `clear`. To make `clear` a member a friend, if I understand correctly, `Window_mgr` must be defined. To define `Window_mgr`, `Screen` must be defined. This seems impossible to me.

The text gives the following hints:

> Making a member function a friend requires careful structuring of our programs to accommodate interdependencies among the declarations and definitions. In this example, we must order our program as follows:
>
> - First, define the `Window_mgr` class, which declares, but does not define, `clear`. `Screen` must be declared before `clear` can use members of `Screen`.
> - Next, define class `Screen`, including a friend declaration for `clear`.
> - Finally, define `clear`, which can now refer to members in `Screen`.

The order in which I attempted to solve this exercise was ultimately this:

```
class Screen;

class Window_mgr
{
  public:
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear(ScreenIndex);
  private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{Screen(24, 80 ' ')};
};

class Screen
{
  friend Window_mgr::clear(Window_mgr::ScreenIndex);
  public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) { }
  private:
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;
};

void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
  Screen &s = screens[i];
  s.contents = std::string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}
```

This obviously would not work, due to the vector in `Window_mgr` that needs `Screen` to be a complete type. This seems like an unsolvable exercise, unless the authors do not intend one to use `Screen` and `Window_mgr` classes they present earlier.

Has anyone else solved this exercise from C++ Primer. If so, how? Any help how this can be done, or as my gut tells me, cannot be done?

Comment: "First, define the `Window_mgr` class [...] Next, define class `Screen`" That sounds like `Window_mgr` shall not have (non-pointer non-reference) members of type `Screen` (or, in this case `std::vector<Screen>`).

Comment: Yes, so that's what I was thinking as well, but clearly their definition of `clear` uses the vector they define in `Window_mgr`. It really seems like it's a badly thought out exercise.

Comment: I supposed using a `std::shared_ptr<Screen>` vector is off the table, eh.

Comment: Even if using a `std::shared_ptr<Screen>`, the `Window_mgr` class, as designed by the authors, initializes the vector with a default screen and would need to have a defined non-default constructor, no?

Comment: @Adam You can define your own default constructor, but you had to define it yourself, after the definition of `Screen`.

Comment: You can do it regardless. The authors default can be moved to the initializer list of the WindowMgr constructor. [See It Live](http://ideone.com/3tLXyl)

Comment: I think this might be a bit more complicated. The question is whether or not incomplete types are allowed as template argument for `std::vector`, and I can't find anything specific about it in the Standard atm.

Comment: Collecting some hints from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18672346/420683), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8329826/420683) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3074872/420683), it seems the solution to this problem relies on undefined behaviour. The Standard seems not to allow incomplete types as `value_type` for `std::vector`, but only for historic reasons. Some (most?) of the recent major implementations of the StdLib however do support incomplete `value_type`s (at least for `vector`).

Comment: @DyP I learned what I could from this exercise. I wouldn't use such a design really, it was more of an academic exercise. `clear` belongs in `Screen` and `Screen` needs to be defined before `Window_mgr`. That side-steps the whole friends issue, and the vector issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [class.friend]/5 says :

> When a friend declaration refers to an overloaded name or operator, only the function specified by the parameter types becomes a friend. A member function of a class X can be a friend of a class Y.

In your specific case :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Screen;

class Window_mgr
{
  public:

    Window_mgr();

    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear(ScreenIndex);
  private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens;
};

class Screen
{
  friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);
  public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) { }
  private:
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;
};


Window_mgr::Window_mgr():
  screens{1, Screen(24, 80, ' ') }
{
}

void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
  Screen &s = screens[i];
  s.contents = std::string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}

int main()
{
  Window_mgr w;
  w.clear(0);
}
```

---

Take a note that it is not possible to solve that exercise, because Window_mgr has a member variable of std::vector which argument is an incomplete type. It will work on most compilers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330131/476681) why), but the standard prohibits it.

This example demonstrates how to make a member function friend of a class :

```
#include <iostream>

struct A;

struct B
{ 
  void bar( A& a, int l);
};

struct A
{
  friend void B::bar(A&,int);
  A():k(0){}
  private:
  void foo(int m);
  int k;
};



void A::foo(int m)
{
  std::cout<<"A::foo() changing from "<<k<<" to "<<m<<std::endl;
  k=m;
}

void B::bar( A& a, int l)
{
  std::cout<<"B::bar() changing to "<<l<<std::endl;
  a.foo(l);
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  b.bar(a,11);
}
```

Comment: @DyP Leaving to OP to do his homework, I added another example, which demonstrates what I meant. It has to be defined.

Comment: I understand that a class needs to be defined before you can declare members of it as friends. In your second example, you defined B before declaring a member of B as a friend in A. The problem I have is that I cannot define the equivalent of B first, because it has a vector of A.

Comment: @Adam I don't see why not. See how I solved your exercise in the latest edit

Comment: I'm astonished this works. I don't see any rule allowing `std::vector` to have an incomplete `value_type`, although I can imagine how it internally works. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8329826/420683)

Comment: I'm astonished it worked. I assumed the compiler saying I was using an incomplete type for Screen on the Vector line to be the Vector itself, but it was the call to the constructor it didn't like.

Comment: @DyP Yes, I have seen similar questions, but I think that the type is completely defined at the moment of instantiation.

Comment: @DyP I was too, until I realized `std::vector<Screen>` uses `Screen` internally for pointer and reference decls; *not* as an instance. Prove this by removing the vector and just putting `Screen screen;` there. It will break immediately.

Comment: @WhozCraig Quoting myself ;) "I can imagine how it internally works" The question is if it's guaranteed to work, UB or ill-formed.

Comment: @BЈовић "I think that the type is completely defined at the moment of instantiation" Well, what is the point of instantiation here? I think [temp.point]/3 applies here "Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately precedes the namespace scope declaration or definition that refers to the specialization."

Comment: @DyP I can/would hardly believe `std::vector<>` is that defined. And I like you was astonished that `std::vector<Screen>`::value_type is even *available* (and now that I think about it, I don't think it is... yet).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah! I knew I've seen this just recently. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18672346/420683). There's a hint in the Standard under a section about functions, but it seems it indeed is UB.

Comment: @DyP yeah, i'd rather not rely on it just on that alone. If I was told to do this I'd quietly go into that good night with a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Screen>>`. At least I'm *sure* thats not UB. (whether this is, or isn't, I can't claim to be intimate enough with the standard to swing a gavel).

Comment: @BЈовић "I think that the type is completely defined at the moment of instantiation" For the member functions of `std::vector`, yes. They're only implicitly instantiated when called, and at that time (in this example) the type `Screen` is complete (that's why it works). However, for the class template specialization `std::vector<Screen>` itself (i.e., the type itself), the point of instantiation is *before* `Screen` is complete.

Comment: @DyP It is easily demonstrable that forcing that instantiation early can/will break this. I.e. `std::vector<Screen>::value_type m_scr;` will obviously not work.

Comment: @BЈовић How to separate the two classes into two files? Thank you!