# Trick to allow incomplete types in templates?

Tags: c++, stl, incomplete-type

C++ STL containers don't allow instantiation with incomplete types; it is undefined behavior.

Is this a valid "trick" to get around that restriction? Or does this trick still have undefined behavior?

```
#include <vector>

template<template<class, class> class Vector = std::vector>
struct my_incomplete_vector
{
    struct Element;

    // Element is incomplete here, but does it matter anymore?
    typedef Vector<Element, std::allocator<Element> > type;

    struct Element { typename type::iterator value; };
};

int main()
{
    my_incomplete_vector<>::type v;
    v.resize(1);

    // this isn't normally possible without incomplete types
    v[0].value = v.begin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't "store types in containers". You store *objects* in containers.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I fixed it, but your point?

Comment: The question was vacuous as it was... why is the sky made of bricks etc.

Comment: I did not see any incomplete types here.

Comment: @JohnSmith `Element` is incomplete when it's used to define `type`.

Comment: inside class/struct, isn't any member is available regardless their relative position?

Comment: @JohnSmith No.  What makes you think that?  (Inside a member function, all class members are available, even if the function is defined within the class.  But otherwise, there are no special rules.)

Comment: Related fact: There are already [text books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18905090/420683) which rely on the implementations to allow using incomplete types as parameters of StdLib containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undefined behavior.  The standard requires a type to be
complete if it is used as the argument of a template, at the
point where the template is instantiated.  And 
`my_incomplete_vector::Element` is not complete when you use it
inside `Element`.  No problems will occur until you actually
instantiate your template, of course, but g++ fails to compile
your code with the usual debugging options
(`-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC`).

Comment: Isn't this is similiar to `struct T { T * p;}`? `T` is not complete but is OK to define a pointer/iterator?

Comment: @JohnSmith a type doesn't have to be complete to have a pointer to it declared.

Comment: @JohnSmith No. `struct T { T* p; }` has nothing to do with the requirements on a template argument.  In order to declare a variable of type `type::iterator`, `type` must be instantiated.  And the standard says that when a template is instantiated, the type is is instantiated over must be complete (with a couple of exceptions).  I don't see any relationship with pointers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't understand what exactly is undefined here though. At the point of instantiation of `vector<Element>`, `Element` is already defined, isn't it? When is `vector<Element>` instantiated with an incomplete `Element` type?

Comment: @JohnSmith: For any object type `T`, `T*` is a complete type.

Comment: @Mehrdad: FWIW, VS 2012 (VC++11) compiles it just fine.

Comment: @Dilip: Yup that's where I originally tested it.

Comment: @Mehrdad No.  The point of instantiation of `vector<Element>` is inside the class `Element`, so `Element` is still an incomplete type.

Comment: @Dilip Which is one possible result of undefined behavior.  The committee wanted to require a diagnostic for this in C++11, but this depended on concepts, which for various reasons didn't get in.